# Composite and Covering index

Tags: sql-server

What is the diffrence between composite index and covering index in Sql Server ?

Answer (score 3):

A covering index is a composite index that contains every column you are currently retrieving with your select statement and that participates in the where clause. It is one of the best ways to improve query performance substantially.

Answer (score 1):

A covering index is a composite index that covers (hence the name) all columns that are necessary to fulfill a query or a join condition.

There is nothing special about SQL server here, these are generic designations.

Comment: Indexes aren't covered by ANSI standard - it's luck that vendors haven't named the functionality differently.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I suspect that the names were coined by computer scientists and not by DB vendors.

Answer (score 1):

A composite index is also a covering index when the index contains your search criteria and all the data your query is attempting to retrieve. In this example:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM Foo WHERE a = 'FooFoo'
```

A covering index would contain column a (your search predicate) as well as the columns b and c.

In this case SQL Server is optimized to return those values found in the index and does not need to make an additional look up in the actual table. If b and c are frequently returned but rarely searched on then the index might be set up such that b and c are included in the index but not indexed.

Before SQL Server 2005 DBA's would add additional 'covering' columns to their indexes to achieve this optimization. In SQL Server 2005 an additional feature was added that allowed you to include covering columns in the leaf nodes of the index that were not part of the index tree. When creating an index you can specify additional 'covering' columns in the include clause. These columns will not be indexed but added to the leaf node of the index saving SQL Server from looking up the additional data in the main table. Adding the data to the include clause saves SQL Server the overhead of adding the additional data to the search tree while gaining the optimization that a covering index brings.